# Galen framework not generating reports

Tags: selenium, layout, galen

I am trying Galen Framework for one of my site using a Mac. I am able to generate the report, but the reports throws some error which is shown below.

[image: Galen Issues]

I am trying the command:

```
galen check homepage.gspec --url http://testapp.galenframework.com/ --size 1024x768 --htmlreport report
```

I have correctly mapped the gecko driver but not able to fix the above issues. Any help?

Comment: Do you have firefox installed on  your machine?. please update the question title, it is not matching with discription.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I am new to Galen and have done enough research before posting this here. I am expecting some help from Selenium experts if anything could be done to eliminate the errors.

Comment: Yes I have Mozilla installed

Answer (score 1):

I updated Mozilla to the latest version and it worked!